# How To Run a Litecoin Node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, litecoin, nodes

> How To Run Litecoin Node? I want to run my own litecoin node like bitcoin
>   
> I know how to run bitcoin node but there is some issue when i am starting litecoin node

Any Idea? #Creating Litecoin Configuration File (litecoin.conf) and installing dependencies to run litecoin full node

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell us which error you get.

Comment: Thanks @MCCCS Actually i am not getting any error,  I just want know step by step process to run litecoin node, An hour ago i have solved my problem now in my system litecoin node is fully synced

Answer (score 1):

> **Here is how to install and Launch LiteCoin Core daemon on your machine :-)**

A Litecoin full node for building applications and services with Node.js

1. Download Litecoin core from official website https://litecoin.org/

 =>extract that file
2. tar -zxvf litecoin-0.16.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

=>install it
3. sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin ~/litecoin-0.16.0/bin/*

=> Create configuration file
4. now create configuration file(~./litecoin/litecoin.conf)

=>now start litecoin node with daemon
5. litecoind